# Mock data within Laravel to be used with Vue.js

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I am prototyping a little SPA with Laravel and Vue.js and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas how I could quickly mock the data without having to create the model, migration and sample data etc?

I was thinking I could create the model and mock the data and return it in my controller but I am not sure how I would mock the data... Would I create an instance of the model and then assign the data to it? If so how would I do it?

*I am not looking to mock the data in unit tests, I am looking to mock the data within the controller.*

Sorry if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following in your function

```
$user = new User(['name' => 'Taylor', 'lastName' => 'Otwell'])

return $user
```

this way you can return a new user model without having to save anything

Comment: yeah, I was thinking along these lines. I think is actually pretty simple really.